# With OR Without you? WCF service consideration. Using WCF or Just Direct Access?

Tags: wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

This is a design question, I guess there going to be several suggestions (I hope so!)

We are a small travelling agent office, we are developing a software for our need. We have 30 clients on the local LAN, sometime later some other 5-10 from outside the office. (This will be agents on route). 
Would you create a WCF service for this scenario or just leave the DL in the client (for direct access to the SQL)??

Our DataAccess Technology is EntityFramework 4.0 (4.1), ALL clients are Windows 7 based.

About the travelling agents, wouldn't it be much more simple to just use a VPN for the agents connection?? 
We have plans to supply our guides (outside the office ) with 3G tablets in about 1 year from now.

Developing clients with a DL is of course much more straight forward solution, but our plans for the near future will require some kind of service. The tablets application will have a much more simple interface and functionality. So maybe developing a WCF service dedicated for the tablets will be better?
Our first consideration is time, we are in great need for a working software.

Well, I hope I managed to share with you our thoughts clearly enough.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: This is a fine question (although quite broad), but please update your title so that it summarises your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [direct acces database vs web service](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530551/direct-acces-database-vs-web-service)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think one technology that would be a) very well-suited to your needs, and b) doesn't impose a huge overhead on your development effort would be **WCF Data Services**.

This is a REST-based WCF service based on a model - like your Entity Framework model.

Check out:

- the [WCF Data Services Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/bb931106)
- MSDN docs on [WCF Data Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc668792%28VS.100%29.aspx)

I would see clear benefits in architecting a new solution from the get-go to use a service-based approach - even if your local LAN client might end up not using that service layer. Thinking in services, thinking also about the limitations of sending data across a potentially slower link than your LAN usually helps avoid silly mistakes like loading 200'000 customers into a dropdown box and stuff like that...

Having a service layer also makes your client app much less dependent on the actual database technology - that client might be a Winforms, WPF or Silverlight app, a web site, a tablet - you name it. If they all share the service layer, development of the client app will become less of a burden - the majority of your work will be in your data model and your service layer (which is shared across all clients).