# Should we use webservices or do direct database access

Tags: database, wcf

Should we use webservices or do direct database access. Ofcourse direct DB access is relatively faster and also with webservices it is good if we have to make for multiple platforms. 
 is the time significantly high in case of accessing data through a webservice as against a DB call or is it marginally high ?

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530551/direct-acces-database-vs-web-service

Comment: It depends on your architecture. Are multiple applications going to use your Data Access Layer? Is it a big enterprise application or are you developing a small utility? There is also the middle way: Entity Framework (or another OR/m)

Comment: Focuse on your maintainability.Performance should be optimized afterwards when it becomes an issue.

Answer (score 3):

I would have to disagree with TruthOf42 in that web services are best practices for data access. There is certainly a big shift towards that approach these days, but I don't think common use is the same as best practice. Just because something is common/popular doesn't mean it's the best fit for all situations.

Why use web services?

1. If you plan on having more than one application use a generic data access layer.
2. If you plan on exposing your data to external clients.
3. If you want to draw some hard physical lines between your application and the database.

I would argue making web service calls will always be slower than just writing queries against the database. But you can mitigate the issues with wise network planning and caching.

I agree with Aphelion in that if it's a simple application, then keep it simple.

A good idea would be to make an interface in your code that gets data and you start with a database implementation. If you find you'd like to introduce web services later, then you can keep the same interface and just implement a version that makes web service calls instead of directly dialing the database.

Comment: @ryan1234 Do you mean an interface like a programming interface oop kind?

Comment: Yeah a programming interface.

Answer (score 1):

Don't try to optimize something you haven't even written yet. It's best practices to use web services. Doing direct calls to the database just opens you to more security issues.

The most important thing when writing software is writing it well, speed is usually of last concern.