# Sequelize REST API generator

Tags: node.js, postgresql, rest, orm, sequelize.js

I am developing a Nodejs application and my database is Postgres and I am using Sequelize as my ORM because of its excellent support for migrations.

I am on the lookout for a good REST API generator based on the schema I have defined. There are two main hurdles I am facing and they are that the generators don't do a good job of creating association API routes and lack of ACL support.
On the associations front, my schema has multiple levels of association i.e. for example..

```
Student.hasMany(Courses);
Courses.hasMany(Subjects);
```

So ideally the generated REST API should be something like

```
/student/:student_id/course/:course_id/subject/:subjectId
```

I found a few projects that are doing this, but are incomplete.

- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize-restful - is good but does not have ACL support
- https://www.npmjs.org/package/restizr - is in alpha stage and does not generate API routes for associations.

Is there any module that supports this?

Comment: are you set on using using a generator? Or are you open to the likes of express.js, requires a bit more bootstrapping but it will do the job.

Comment: I am ok with express.. the thing is, all CRUD operations are same. Only the model changes, and so I am looking for a solution where based on the model, the route is generated or handled

Comment: Have you ever head of [Loopback](http://strongloop.com/node-js/loopback/) by StrongLoop? It supports MongoDB, Postgres, and MySQL in the community edition. It will generate your routes and models for you based on a schema. Its essentially going to do everything you just described. I encourage you to look into it.

Comment: Thanks @tsturzl.. Loopback looks good.. and am still thinking of how best to use it, but loopback is more of a whole kitchen sink of features.. if I use that, then I am tying myself very closely with StrongLoop's suggested way of doing things..

Comment: I need a generator for my models, I want to be able to closely control all other aspects of my application and write it myself..

Comment: @Sharath Understood, but I'm not aware of you're intentions so I figured this may serve as a viable option.

Comment: There's also https://github.com/dchester/epilogue which is recommended by sequelize-restful which is no longer actively maintained, but it too is still a work in progress

Comment: Check if this can help https://github.com/arorarahul/node-restful-api

Comment: I'm thinking you could profit from querystring, like this: `url?student=id&course=id&subject=id`, then you just process it as an object, validate the keys and types, pass it to your db and return the values. It shouldn't be more than a few lines of code, and you could make a validator function that takes validation schemas and queries, and returns what the request was. The better its coded, the more similar it'll be to the generator you want, and the easier it'll be to get the data.

Comment: Are you with plain Node.js or are you using TypeScript?

Comment: How much configuration are you looking to do? I've been quite happy with NestJS but I believe it will require some tweaking to do exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What you were doing here is writing a webservice without a domain model. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anemic_domain_model Ofc. you have every right to do it, but I wonder if you really understood what a webservice means. https://stackoverflow.com/a/1530607/607033 It is not a database with CRUD HTTP interface normally, though nowadays it is popular doing something this way and call it REST. A response to a REST HTTP request is a viewmodel https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/425001/65755 and it contains not just data, but a lot of metadata and hyperlinks. A REST API is a special type of webservice with many constraints. [https://www.ics.uci.edu/~fielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf](https://www.ics.uci.edu/%7Efielding/pubs/dissertation/fielding_dissertation.pdf) http://www.markus-lanthaler.com/research/hydra-a-vocabulary-for-hypermedia-driven-web-apis.pdf Your ORM is used 2 layers deeper in the data layer and it has nothing to do with the presentation layer where your REST API should be. I really wonder why people are making applications, which are doing nothing except serving data directly from the database and use the most inconvenient technology to do it. I guess there are databases nowadays with ACL and REST API support, so all you need is just using them. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/sql/ Or there was something for PgSQL and Nodejs too around the time you asked this. https://github.com/QBisConsult/psql-api