# What is the advantage of using a direct sql connection vs a web api when retrieving data?

Tags: python, sql, web-services

I have a really old piece of code that I am planning to refactor.

Basically, what this application does is extract data from `Database A` that is stored on `Server A`, process the extracted data and save it to  `Database Z` that is stored on `Server Z`. The retrieval & saving of data is done via `urllib.request`.

Not only do I have `Database A` that is stored on `Server A`, I have several database stored on separate servers as well. (i.e. `Database B` on `Server B`, `Database C` on `Server C`) but all this data goes to `Database Z`.

Now here's the catch, *application.py* is deployed on `Servers A,B,C, ..` and runs **multiple schedules** and sometimes **simultaneously** as well. `Database A,B,C, ..` have the same table structure except for `Database Z`.

With the current design, I can execute my application wherever I am as long as I have an internet connection if need be. I just pass the `Server X` parameter and viola, process complete.

But this design got me thinking on whether I should change my application design to retrieve the data via odbc instead of getting the data via web.

Should I switch from retrieving data via web requests to querying data via odbc?

Please shed some light as to what is the pro's and con's on using a direct sql connection vs retrieving data via web api for my specific scenario.

Note: I don't mind not being able to run the application wherever I am as long as the transition is for the greater good. I might as well remote the servers and execute the application from there.

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1530551/direct-acces-database-vs-web-service

Comment: Thank you for this info, though based on their discussion, the accepted answer 'is a wash'. Does this apply for my question as well? Since my application has access to multiple server atm via web access, should I just stick to this design? Or modify the application to access the data via odbc for each server since the application is deployed on every server?